# Get distinct count with condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

How can I simply calculate COUNT of distinct ControlNo only where TYPE column is = 'New Business'. But I need to do it in a query that will be join to a calendar table.

```
SELECT      underwriter,
            --ControlNo,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business' AND RevisedStatus IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  'Binds - NEW BUSINESS',
            SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Renewal'      AND RevisedStatus IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  'Binds - RENEWALS',
            SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Rewrite'      AND RevisedStatus IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  'Binds - REWRITE',


            SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  Submissions1,
            count(  case when type = 'New Business' then ControlNo  else 0 end) as Submissions2,


            b.MonthNum,
                b.YearNum,
                b.MonthName

FROM        tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN   Test_Plaza_ClearanceReport a ON b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate)    
            AND b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
            AND a.Underwriter ='Brown, Debra'
WHERE       b.YearNum = 2016
GROUP BY
                b.MonthName,
                b.MonthNum,
                b.YearNum,
                --ControlNo,
                underwriter
```

I have slightly different result. Which one I should trust?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would express this as:

```
  count(distinct  case when type = 'New Business' then ControlNo  end) as UniqueValues
```

Note:  There is no `else`; without it, the expression evaluates to `NULL` and the values are not counted.